# Angular.js - currently selected option's value inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have entries, their json object looks somewhat like this

```
{ 
    'id': 5,
    'activityId': 1
}
```

then I have activities, their json object  looks like this

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Activity name',
    'rate': 1200
}
```

now I'm rendering entries like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    <td>
        <activities></activities>
    </td>
    <td>
        // here's supposed to be the rate
    </td>
</tr>
```

where activities is a directive that looks like this

```
app.directive("activities", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select ng-model="entry.activityId" ng-options="a.id as a.name for a in activities"></select>'
    }
});
```

now what would I need to do, to be able to print the rate inside my ng-repeat? Since it's an attribute of something that's inside the directive, but I need it printed outside the directive.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
{{(activities | filter:{id: entry.activityId})[0].rate}}
```

though I find this a bit ugly. A better way would be to add the activity directly as a property of your entities, maybe after loading both data-sets. Another way would be a self-made filter that also checks for errors (e.g. activityId not found, etc.).

http://plnkr.co/edit/4ljEdDFPBpOzueFuI6FT

Comment: So in my controller I would load entries and activities, then loop thru entries and add activities to each entry.. But I'd have to use kind of the same filter there too, wouldn't I?

Comment: What if I, in my controller, looped thru entries, and copied rate from the activity with id == activityId and then on select change in the directive I'd update that?

Comment: @foxx Yes, either in a service or inside the controller loop through the entries and assign the correct activity. For this you could essentially use the same construct as in my answer. The reason this is better is because the loop is only done once, instead of countless times (updates, etc.). Regarding your second comment. I would not copy the rate into the entry, as this is redundant data.

Comment: Wait, I would assign it only the activity with the right ID? That's not much different to my other comment then is it? Just instead copying only the rate, I would copy the whole activity object..

Comment: @foxx Not quite. Because if you copy the rate, you copy the value. So if for any reason you later change the rate on the activity it would not be reflect on the entry. But if you assign the activity you assign by reference. So a change to the rate would be reflected in both places.

Comment: Well you can't really change the rate on the same page, so it shouldn't be a problem. But if it's the proper way of doing it.. Anyway, I'm sorry but I'm probably gonna needs a bit more spoon feeding :/ I suppose that this is not the reference assigning you were talking about http://plnkr.co/edit/5gk379gZ0qjVtEMj5rZd

Comment: @foxx Almost, just change your activities directive to `<select ng-model="entry.activity" ng-options="a as a.name for a in activities">`

Comment: one more thing though, the function I'm using to get the activity with the right ID, doesn't Angular have anything like that built in? I mean, the filter you were using in your answer, would that work inside a controller as well?

Comment: @foxx yes you can inject the filter into your controller, see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filter

Comment: So I have a little problem.. when I'm trying to save the whole form, values of the selects are taken from incremental order of options.. So when I select activity1, which would have id, say `my_activity_id_47jsad4` on `select name="activity"`, then tried to send it, post would look like this `{activity: 1}`, instead of `{activity: my_activity_id_47jsad4}`

Comment: Also @Yoshi by changing the ng-model to entry.activity, the original entry.activityId won't update.. also plnkr for the problem above  http://plnkr.co/edit/v8WK4aZlbONY8rz5Lgb6?p=preview

Comment: @foxx Personally I would not submit the form using "the normal submit" when using angular, but rather submit it through ajax using [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http). If that's not possible, I'd use a hidden input for the actual value, e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="%name%" value="{{entry.activity.id}}">`.

Comment: Alright then, that makes sesnse, but I still don't quite get this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501930/angular-js-currently-selected-options-value-inside-ng-repeat/15502438?noredirect=1#comment22041718_15502438 also if I updated ACTIVITIES it wouldn't update activity on ENTRIES, would it? // edit it actually does.. I don't understand it at all